# i am hitting this keepa api but data is coming like this

Tags: php, laravel

```
public function CallAPI($method, $url, $data = false)
{
    $curl = curl_init();

    switch ($method)
    {
        case "POST":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);

            if ($data)
                curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
            break;
        case "PUT":
            curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_PUT, 1);
            break;
        default:
            if ($data)
                $url = sprintf("%s?%s", $url, http_build_query($data));
    }

    // Optional Authentication:
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_BASIC);

    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    $result = curl_exec($curl);

    curl_close($curl);

    return $result;
}
```

---

```
$res = CallAPI('GET',
        'https://api.keepa.com/product?key=786fc09u868cl88g4llvppn511v5ihdbld3tjqq8mom28rtac4crijm5u4rerk43&asin=0134472098&domain=1'
       );
```

> ��ĝɮuKvV��7(��v��,AǢgѰ���3-g~y4ƌXk���q���;�b�,��?���~��������_�e��[�{~����o�����?��_�^�_�������ۿ��/���g��˿��o�����������o����O�����5��tK�7�����~�O���?���?��o~������~�w�������u�g~��_~����o���~������1wJ�2RI��gMi}J�u}j���rieռǧ�6˧��ˈ/��V^Zm���h�ҧ��K�h5�h,PO�/kmQi�F�����K+y�% �:HZ-���F���oڨy}J���ZM�R�ܢ-��EC�gMP�c���dk�M�s����-��.�L���w�d�2wI��+c]�J�Z���7%�b)�V�Q,eY_��RV�z�(eX�Q��#���0���m}�0�N.�c���5K��Wz����F�R�m�1��ޖգ��}wJ��5Uj�R����)�&{[K��������.zԭ�&VQIӶ��E1#ef3�Č�x�]�u���]�-U��R���d-��7�<��>A����v-���������0��6����7h�s��]d)u�"j�Rf�/�q��E#P|9�_m�/��j�R�k}j����O�f������fcvJu��j��RG��F T���Η3h��ל�e�����R{�kQ�v�AK�����Ҋ����=�鵩o�Xg�ܞ%%���Z�rv}m{���/g��^i{��h�@��^�>��*1�%��^%{��kp�(űΕӭ�T,�rN��j�����iK�~�v����8�r�쥯����r}i5'��K�� ���]+�����\��z�5ѥu�����U_��Ї6��d��>�YX��� �yQ��>礝�1}�2���Uw��r�l���;�͙�Q�k0�9>uԶ�re��:'7WΜR�9��w3i�98����̢��Ν/ӮTg��ae�=G���Lym�ڝytz���:K���V��� �u��e��]PRgngM���:{s�<����k�Z�VPu}�2k_ T8[g���Ou�%��>����R�哻k~��ݟ�����>�����'�-E�R�cľ�䕸��Nm�O;S�ޮ��8wW���.�U@+�z��U���W��c�����2�����{h}�/��A������Ъ|ȥ�������5n���m٥������И�����y;ݾ��<_�B;Zߴ��i��Z����Y�_4n؇����*��C�zh��w�{%��*Y�.��A}��r�2gH��+���

Comment: If Laravel why don't you use HTTP Client?

Comment: try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, 'UTF-8');` or use HTTP Client that  autodetects the encoding.